# Should i save long instances of text in SQLite, StringArrays or Internal Storage?

Tags: android, sqlite

Im building an android app for learning a language. I have written the lessons in a word doc so far. So now i am wondering how i should save these lessons within the app.

There are 5 lessons, each lesson consists of 500-1000 words and should have an audio file with it.
I have successfully implement this with string arrays inside a class, ala:

```
public class Lecture {
    static String[] LectureContent = {
        "First lesson ...",
        "Second lesson ..."
    };
}
```

But i am wondering if it would be better to use SQLite, but how should i go about doing that? 
Should i create a table "Lesson" e.g. String query = "CREATE TABLE lesson( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, lessonContent TEXT, " + "AudioFile FILE)";

Let the _ID stand for the lesson number than just populate the lessonContent with the text. Should i populate this in the onCreate in my application or somewhere else.

Worth to note is that i want to add additional lessons later, i.e. update the app with new lessons.

Please help. Ive thinking about this too long now.

Comment: That would be a lot of html files after a while. Lets say i develop 50 lessons. Than should i have 50 html files included in the projects resources folder?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Sqlite table with one per Language or feature. That would allow you to dynamically load new profiles and languages through a modular system a bit later on. You probably have way too much memory allocated and loaded at the moment for a text based app. it is probably a bit slow because of it as well.

If you go towards providing an API for other apps, having a Sqlite based approach can save a LOT of pain (moving towards Content Providers which is part of having lessons later).

With a Content Provider, you have can other apps and installs of other languages actually go an make their own table, load their own table, or simply add to an existing table. Then, each has a unique identifier so that the main Content Provider can identify the apps installed for content authorization. You can do this to prevent some piracy.

You get speed and dependability with minimal effort. You can use the Sdcard, but the lockups can be comparatively slow when going against something like a flat file, XML, and even JSON. Also, SQLite DBs can be stored on the SD.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I dont really understand, would using SQL make the app faster? I thought the opposite. As it is with the LectureContent array now, loading the lessons are instantaneous even in the VM.

Im quite new to SQLite, but did you say that the table i wrote would be ok? But how should i insert the text to the lessons? I mean, how could i populate the database so it is already "full" when somebody downloads it. I though about doing it in the activitys onCreate, but that would load alot of data each time the user starts it. So that must be wrong.